# @Bean ResourceProcessor with @Autowired

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rest

In my Spring Boot 1.5.10 application with Spring Data REST and HATEOAS, I have a `ResourceProcessor` bean with an `@Autowired` service, like:

```
@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<Resource<Order>> orderResourceProcessor() {
    return new ResourceProcessor<Resource<Order>>() {
        @Autowired
        private OrderHandler orderHandler;

        @Override
        public Resource<Order> process(Resource<Order> resource) {
            Order order = resource.getContent();
            Payment payment = orderHandler.payment(order);

            resource.add(makeLink(payment));

            return resource;
        }

        private Link makelink(Payment payment) {
            return new Link(/*...*/);
        }
    };
}
```

When the `@Autowired` service is added, the resource processor bean is no longer triggered, unfortunately; i.e., when `OrderHandler` is commented out, the resource processor runs as it should.

Can a `ResourceProcessor` use `@Autowired` services; and, if so, what's the right way to construct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the [`@Bean` annotation javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) should interest you :

**@Bean Methods in @Configuration Classes**

> Typically, @Bean methods are declared within @Configuration classes.
>   In this case, bean methods may reference other @Bean methods in the
>   same class by calling them directly. This ensures that references
>   between beans are strongly typed and navigable. Such so-called
>   'inter-bean references' are guaranteed to respect scoping and AOP
>   semantics, just like getBean() lookups would.

Example :

```
 @Bean
 public FooService fooService() {
     return new FooService(fooRepository());
 }

 @Bean
 public FooRepository fooRepository() {
     return new JdbcFooRepository(dataSource());
 }
```

It means that you have not to use `@Autowired` to set the dependency inside the `@Bean` declaration but reference another method annotated with `@Bean`.
But do you really need to set the dependency to create your bean ? 
No at all.  The OrderHandler is used only during the `process()` invocation.

So you can simply inject `OrderHandler` at the same level that the method annotated with `@Bean` and using it in the anonymous class :

```
@Autowired
private OrderHandler orderHandler;  // only change

@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<Resource<Order>> orderResourceProcessor() {
    return new ResourceProcessor<Resource<Order>>() {


        @Override
        public Resource<Order> process(Resource<Order> resource) {
            Order order = resource.getContent();
            Payment payment = orderHandler.payment(order);

            resource.add(makeLink(payment));

            return resource;
        }

        private Link makelink(Payment payment) {
            return new Link(/*...*/);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can Autowire orderHandler to outer class. In your way it will not work as you create the instance of ResourceProcessor yourself.

```
@Autowired
private OrderHandler orderHandler;

@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<Resource<Order>> orderResourceProcessor() {
   return new ResourceProcessor<Resource<Order>>() {


    @Override
    public Resource<Order> process(Resource<Order> resource) {
        Order order = resource.getContent();
        Payment payment = orderHandler.payment(order);

        resource.add(makeLink(payment));

        return resource;
    }

    private Link makelink(Payment payment) {
        return new Link(/*...*/);
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Trying your suggestion revealed the underlying problem which is a (not shown) circular dependency...which is swallowed silently in Spring. :-/

Comment: In any case that @Autowire as you use  will not work.

Comment: Hey. You changed with my answer. Please be fair.

Comment: @davidxxx it is true that after I saw your answer I realized the implementation is an anonymous class. I fixed my code. What do you want me to do exactly return it back to old version?

Comment: @cool  Change nothing. You answer is fair :) You have my vote : your answer started from a good point.